# How to abort program using threads in c?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I've written the program, which is scanning folders and want to stop its running always when user types 'q'. In win it's simple - getch() fuction. In linux it's harder to do and my teacher told me to use threads if i want to run my program both in win and linux. The question is how? I've already written smth like this:

```
void exit_stat()
{
            int x=0;
    char d;
    while(x==0)
    {
        d=getchar();
        if(d=='q')
        exit;
    }
}
```

and in main:

```
pthread_t threads[1];
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, exit_stat, NULL);
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need `exit(0);`, if you do `exit;` that (conceptually) looks up a function pointer, then throws it away without calling it. Calling `exit` is equivalent to doing `return` from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your main() monitoring stdin, and then when it receives the 'q' command from the user, have it tell your scanning-thread to go away.  In C++ you could use a std::atomic boolean to do that pretty easily, but since you asked about C, here is a solution that uses a socket-pair to do the notification.  In particular, when the main() thread wants the scan_thread to terminate, it indicates that desire by closing its own end of the socket-pair connection.  The scan_thread detects that the connection has been closed and responds by terminating itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

static void * scan_thread(void * socketPtr)
{
   int socket1 = *((int *)socketPtr);

   while(1)
   {
      printf("scan_thread:  I'm scanning more files!\n");
      sleep(1);  /* well, I'm pretending to, anyway */

      /* See if the main thread has closed his end of the socket-connection yet.
       * If so, that means it is time for us to clean up and exit.
       */
      char buf;
      int r = recv(socket1, &buf, 1, 0);
      if (r == 0) break;  /* recv() returning 0 indicates that the socket connection has been broken */
   }
   printf("scan_thread is exiting now!\n");

   close(socket1);  /* make sure we don't leak our socket */
   return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   /** Create a pair of sockets that are connected to each other */
   int sockets[2];
   if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockets) != 0)
   {
      perror("socketpair");
      return 10;
   }

   /** Make socket[1] non-blocking so that the scan_thread can check its status without blocking */
   int flags = fcntl(sockets[1], F_GETFL, 0);
   if (fcntl(sockets[1], F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK) != 0)
   {
      perror("fcntl");
      return 10;
   }

   /** spawn the child thread.  Pass him a pointer to his socket, as an argument. */
   pthread_t thread;
   if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, scan_thread, &sockets[1]) != 0)
   {
      perror("pthread_create");
      return 10;
   }

   char buf[128];
   while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
   {
      if (buf[0] == 'q')
      {
         printf("You typed q, time to abort the thread!\n");
         break;
      }
   }

   /** Close our socket.  That will let the scan_thread know its time for him to exit. */
   close(sockets[0]);

   /** Wait for the scan_thread to exit (this is important, to avoid race conditions). */
   (void) pthread_join(thread, NULL);

   printf("main() is ending, bye!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Note however that your teacher wasn't entirely correct about threads being necessary; you can get non-blocking read behavior from stdin under Linux by setting stdin to non-blocking mode.  Here's an example of a program that does the same thing without spawning any extra threads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   /** Set stdin to non-blocking mode so we can read from it without blocking */
   int fd = fileno(stdin);
   int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
   if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK) != 0)
   {
      perror("fcntl");
      return 10;
   }

   while(1)
   {
      printf("I'm scanning more files!\n");
      sleep(1);  /* well, I'm pretending to, anyway */

      char buf[128];
      if ((fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))&&(buf[0] == 'q'))
      {
         printf("You entered q, exiting now!\n");
         break;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```